# Check if todays date exists in a table with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a database table with columns of type `dateTime`.

Now I need to see if there already is a row with today's date, but I don't know how to compare the column with the current date without the hour, minutes, seconds.

Basically I have `2022-02-04 14:06:21.080` and I need to check if there is a row created on `2022-02-04`.

I'm looking for something like

```
if (db.dates.Where(x => x.SentDate == Date.Now).Count() > 0)
{
     // Do something
}
else
{
     // Do something else
}
```

I only need to see if it has a date from today it doesn't matter what time it was created.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check a date range

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);

if(db.dates.Where(x => x.SentDate >= today && x.SentDate < tomorrow) ...
```

The DateTime.Today Property gets the current date with the time component set to 00:00:00.

Answer (score 4):

If you're filtering for a specific date you can use the [`DateTime.Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-6.0) property on both `DateTime` objects. This will compare the date component of the `DateTime`:

```
db.dates.Where(x => x.SentDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
// or
db.dates.Where(x => x.SentDate.Date == DateTime.Today)
```

---

If you have a nullable `DateTime?` column, then you use the `Value` property along with `HasValue`:

```
db.dates.Where(x => x.SentDate.HasValue 
                 && x.SentDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Today)
```

Unfortunately, expression trees do not support the null propagation operator `?.` so we need to use the above method instead.

`DateTime.Date` can also be used for date ranges, but take care with the upper bound.

PS: `DateTime.Today` is the same as `DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: I cant use .Date on x.SentDate i get the error 'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Date' accepting a frist argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found

Comment: @Shatsuki that just means the datetime is nullable. You could try adding a null conditional operator `?` after `SentDate` like  this: `db.dates.Where(x=> x.SentDate?.Date == DateTime.Today)`

Answer (score 2):

You can check a date range

```cs
var today = DateTime.Today;
var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);

if(db.dates.Where(x => x.SentDate >= today && x.SentDate < tomorrow) ...
```

The [DateTime.Today Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime.Today);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-6.0) gets the current date with the time component set to 00:00:00.

Note that we test the lower bound with `>= today` (with `today` meaning today at 00:00:00) but the upper one with `< tomorrow`, since we do not want to include tomorrow at 00:00:00.

Comment: This seems to work i just need to fix my codes logic using this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use MS SQL Server you can use a special function  `EF.Functions.DateDiff` that was created to be used with EF. It can count datetime difference from seconds to months. [`DateDiffDay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datediffday?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions-datediffday(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctions-system-datetime-system-datetime)) is used to count days.

```cs
var  dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
if (db.dates.Any(x => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.SentDate , dateTimeNow) == 0 )
{
    // ... there are today's dates
}
// ...
```

Comment: so what is this exactly gonna do?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to convert the dates to string and compare.

```
 if(db.dates.Any(m=>m.SentDate.ToString("d") == DateTime.Now.ToString("d"))){
    //Do something else
    }
    else
    {
     // Do something else
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).